# In Access, how do I display the id and column name of the column with the highest value in each row?

Tags: sql, ms-access, max

**This is the sample table:**

```
Table1
| id | one | two | three | four | five | six |
|--------------------------------------------|
|   1|   11|    7|      4|     9|     4|    1|
|   2|   12|    9|      3|     8|    19|   32|
|   3|   18|    7|      7|     1|    24|    2|
|   4|    9|    1|     15|     6|     6|    4|
```

**Currently the query I am using on the table is this:**

```
SELECT id, Max(colx) AS colWithMax
FROM (
   SELECT id, one AS Colx From Table1 UNION ALL
   SELECT id, two AS Colx From Table1 UNION ALL
   SELECT id, three AS Colx From Table1 UNION ALL
   SELECT id, four AS Colx From Table1 UNION ALL
   SELECT id, five AS Colx From Table1 UNION ALL
   SELECT id, six AS Colx From Table1
)
group by id;
```

**The output I'm getting is:**

```
ID | colWithMax
-- | ---------
 1 |     11
 2 |     32
 3 |     24
 4 |     15
```

## My question is how can I change my query so my output will show the column name instead of the value in the column?

**Based on the sample table the desired output would be:**

```
ID | colWithMax
-- | --------- 
 1 |   one
 2 |   six
 3 |   five
 4 |   three
```

*Note: I have basic understanding of sql and I have never used ms-access before.  Please be as descriptive as possible in your answers.  Thank you.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's another spin on it without multiple queries using `if`:

```
select  id,
  if (one > two && one > three && one > four && one > five && one > six, 'one',  
  if (two > three && two > four && two > five && two > six, 'two',
  if (three > four && three > five && three > six, 'three',
  if (four > five && four > six, 'four',
  if (five > six, 'five', 'six'))))) col
from Table1
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/17b42/2)

This actually uses `if` where access uses `iif` and this uses `&&` where I think access uses `AND`, but the point is, you don't need to use an aggregate and a `group by` in your query.

Here is my attempt at the access equivalent:

```
select  id,
  iif (one > two AND one > three AND one > four AND one > five AND one > six, 'one',  
  iif (two > three AND two > four AND two > five AND two > six, 'two',
  iif (three > four AND three > five AND three > six, 'three',
  iif (four > five AND four > six, 'four',
  iif (five > six, 'five', 'six'))))) col
from Table1
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  This solution worked for me.  The only thing i had to add was:
    iif (five > six, 'five', 'six'))))) **AS** col

Comment: @Kiro -- np, glad it worked for you!  Haven't used Access in a while and was winging it a bit :)

Answer (score 0):

you can try following query -

```
select id, colname from (   
SELECT id, one AS Colx, 'one' Colname From Table1 UNION ALL
   SELECT id, two AS Colx, 'Two' Colname From Table1 UNION ALL
   SELECT id, three AS Colx, 'Three' colname From Table1 UNION ALL
   SELECT id, four AS Colx, 'four' colname From Table1 UNION ALL
   SELECT id, five AS Colx, 'Five' colname From Table1 UNION ALL
   SELECT id, six AS Colx, 'Six' colname From Table1
) as t1
where exist ( select 1 from (
SELECT id, Max(colx) AS colWithMax
FROM (
   SELECT id, one AS Colx, 'one' Colname From Table1 UNION ALL
   SELECT id, two AS Colx, 'Two' Colname From Table1 UNION ALL
   SELECT id, three AS Colx, 'Three' colname From Table1 UNION ALL
   SELECT id, four AS Colx, 'four' colname From Table1 UNION ALL
   SELECT id, five AS Colx, 'Five' colname From Table1 UNION ALL
   SELECT id, six AS Colx, 'Six' colname From Table1
)
group by id) as t2
where t1.id = t2.id
and  t1.colx = t2.colx)
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to simpify things a bit move this into it's own query (call it what you like but i'll call it `Qry` for the purposes of this answer. As you can see i have added a column for the name of the column from where the value comes.

```
SELECT id, val, col
FROM (
    SELECT id, one AS val, 'one' AS col FROM Table1 UNION ALL
    SELECT id, two AS val, 'two' AS col FROM Table1 UNION ALL
    SELECT id, three AS val, 'three' AS col FROM Table1 UNION ALL
    SELECT id, four AS val, 'four' AS col FROM Table1 UNION ALL
    SELECT id, five AS val, 'five' AS col FROM Table1 UNION ALL
    SELECT id, six AS val, 'six' AS col FROM Table1
) AS Qry
```

In a second/new query that will use the one defined above do something like

```
SELECT q1.id, q1.val, q1.col  AS colWithMax
FROM Qry q1
LEFT JOIN Qry q2 ON q2.id = q1.id
                AND q2.val > q1.val
WHERE q2.id IS NULL
```

the idea being that only the values that do not have a number greater than them will have a join, and so the largest (or max number) should have not have a 'join value', these are identified by the `q2.id IS NULL`